# Where to start for making a program to convert MP3 files to iphone audiobook (M4B) format?

Tags: iphone, c++, audio, mp3

I'm new to programming and want to find something that I can work on to help learn more about it. I want to do this is C++ if possible. What i want to do is start working on developing a program that has a user interface and will convert an mp3 into an m4b (the format iphone uses for audiobooks.  I have been looking for some source code examples but have had no luck. If anyone can give me some places to start that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really trivial with the *Audio Converter Services* that are part of *Core Audio*.

I know it is not cool to just post a book reference but I really highly recommend [Learning Core Audio: A Hands-on Guide to Audio Programming for Mac and iOS](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/audio/9780321636973) if you want to do Core Audio stuff.

Chapter 6 is all about audio conversion from one format to another.

Answer (score 0):

M4B simply is a MP4 file (AAC encoded) with the extension M4B. So it basically is an MP4 file with a renamed file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider using an encoding library such as ffmpeg.